# I have a UIView presented in a view controller, how do I detect when the user tapped outside of this view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a UIView in a view controller with a bunch of subviews (mostly UIButtons) on it, and when the user taps outside of the UIView I want it to be detected so I can run some code. This UIView is a subview of the main view controller's view.

A lot of the answers on StackOverflow point to making a transparent UIButton covering the whole view controller and adding the UIView on top of that and detecting when the UIButton was tapped.

To me that seems a little hacky, but I might be wrong. I'm afraid that in a future release Apple may make it so you can't interact with transparent objects or something, and it will break the solution.

Is this really the best solution? Or is there another way to do it that would be more clean?

Comment: Can You add Images of your View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the uiview in a view controller is named view1

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:view1];


    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(view1.frame, p)) {//when touched out of view1
       //do action
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it's not a good solution to add a Button, there are special classes that are for this :
[TapGesture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I'm aware of tap gesture recognizers, my question is more so how to detect if the touch is outside of the view.

Comment: Ok, you can use the solution of @Mohannad for detecting the CGPoint of the touche and the apply the UIView's instance methode - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Answer (score 0):

The transparent button isn't a bad solution really. But if you need to use another solution, you can use the method `- (void) touchesBegan:withEvent:`. It's defined in `UIResponder`, which both `UIViewController` and `UIView` inherit from. The method is called whenever a touch is not handled by an object in the responder chain before the current object. This means that it won't be called if the touch was on the buttons.

The first parameter is an `NSSet` of `UITouch` objects. You can use `UITouch`'s method `- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view` to tell the exact location from that specific subview. If the location, that is the returned point, is out of the view's bounds, then you can execute the appropriate code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class object instead of UIView and add targets directly to it.